# How do I implement an adcontrol in a gridview so that it'll display 30 items, then the ad, then 30 items and then the ad

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How do I add an adcontrol to a gridview, that I have. (Items page template)

This is the data-template that I use:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Normal">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Height="180">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"
                       Height="40"
                       Margin="15,0,15,0"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use that to display my items, and I want to have ads too. How do  I implement an adcontrol to that, so that it'll display 30 items, then the ad, then 30 items and then the ad. (I have the code to add items, I just don't know how to add ads).

**EDIT**
Okay, I've done all what I should, but now it gives me an error that the namespace could not be found.

**Here's the error:**

```
The name "MyDataTemplateSelector" does not exist in the namespace "using:MyDataSelector"
```

In my main pages XAML code, I've done this:

```
xmlns:selectornamespace="using:MyDataSelector"
```

and here's my page resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
        <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"/>
    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">Sample App</x:String>

    <selectornamespace:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="Selector" AdTemplate="{StaticResource Ad}" NormalTemplate="{StaticResource Normal}"></selectornamespace:MyDataTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>
```

Here's MyDataSelector class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MyDataSelector
{
    private class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate AdTemplate{ get; set; }
        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is TestApp.Mainpage.NormalData)
                return NormalTemplate
            if (item is TestApp.Mainpage.AdData)
                return AdTemplate;

            return SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
        }
    }
}
```

The NormalTemplate and AdTemplate are in StandardStyles.xaml

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks and merry christmas

Comment: May I suggest: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-monetize-windows-8-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [datatemplate selector](http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/data-template-selector-in-windows-8-metro-xaml-app/), then in that detect if the item is just a dummy "Ad" item, then display the add data template instead of you standard template.

You will need to insert a dummy item after every 30th item into your datasource however for this to work

Comment: thanks for the link, I tried it out! :)
Now I have another problem, it can't find the class. Can you help me?

Comment: Thankfully thats easy - make MyDataTemplateSelector public :-)